# How to add a directory to Fish shell PATH from with a Python script?

Tags: python, shell, subprocess, fish

From within a Python-based installation script running on Fish shell and supporting Python 2.7 and 3.4+, I want to add a directory to the `PATH` environment variable if not already present. When the script exits, `PATH` should contain the new directory, both for the current Fish shell session as well as future logins.

To achieve this, I can think of two potential approaches:

1. Create a `localpath.fish` file in `~/.config/fish/conf.d/` containing: `set PATH ~/.local/bin $PATH`
2. Use Python’s `subprocess` to run: `set -U fish_user_paths ~/.local/bin $fish_user_paths`

I would prefer the latter approach, but I have tried invoking Fish via `subprocess` several different ways, all to no avail. For example:

```
>>> subprocess.check_output(["fish", "-c", "echo", "Hello", "World!"], shell=True)
```

On Fish 3.0.2 and Python 3.7.4, the above yields:

```
<W> fish: Current terminal parameters have rows and/or columns set to zero.
<W> fish: The stty command can be used to correct this (e.g., stty rows 80 columns 24).
```

… and the Python REPL prompt does not re-appear. Tapping CTRL-C does not exit properly, leaving the Python REPL in a mostly unusable state until quit and relaunched. (This appears to be a [known issue](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/5909).)

Similarly, using `subprocess.run()` with Python 3.7’s `capture_output` parameter fails to yield the expected output:

```
>>> subprocess.run(["fish", "-c", "echo", "Hello", "World!"], capture_output=True)
CompletedProcess(args=['fish', '-c', 'echo', 'Hello', 'World!'], returncode=0, stdout=b'\n', stderr=b'')
```

My questions:

1. Is there a better strategy than either of the two methods above?
2. If using the first approach, how would I adjust `PATH` for the current Fish shell session from within a Python script?
3. If using the `set -U fish_user_paths […]` approach, what would be the appropriate way to invoke that from within a Python script?

Comment: A subprocess cannot affect its parent process unless you separately arrange for the parent to cooperate. A Python script run from a shell will also be a subprocess of that shell instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track, but the whole command has to be as a single argument. Also you don't want shell expansion beforehand.

So you could write:

```
subprocess.check_output(["fish", "-c", "echo hello world"])
```

and it will do what you expect. For the PATH case:

```
subprocess.check_output(["fish", "-c", "set -U fish_user_paths ~/.local/bin $fish_user_paths"])
```

and this will modify $PATH in the parent process.

Comment: Fantastic. Many thanks for guiding me to the correct invocation!